# Bootstrap container-fluid colliding with floated element

Tags: css, firefox, bootstrap-4, microsoft-edge

I have a card body which contains a floating logo and rows inside a container-fluid

This works perfect in Chrome but has an issue with intendation in Edge and Firefox

Would work with absolute positioning of the logo, but I would like the text to wrap around the image as it does in Chrome

```
<div class="card-body" style="max-width: 400px">                            
    <span class="rounded logo-container" style="float:right;max-width: 40%;">
       <div style="height: 60px; width: 80px;background: red" alt="Logo" ></div>
    </span>
    <p class="mb-1 font-weight-bold">ASDASDASDASD</p>
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col" style="max-width: 6em">sadfasdf:</div>
        <div class="col">sdfasdf</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col" style="max-width: 6em">safdasdfasdf:</div>
        <div class="col">sdfsadfsadfasdf</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col" style="max-width: 6em">sadfasdfsa:</div>
        <div class="col">afsdafs dfsdfsadsdgdfgfs sdfsadf</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

please see the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s2u8y4q0/1/

Comment: It would better if you use two different `section` for a different part.  and use CSS as `width:100%; float: left;` for each section

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, a span shouldn't contain a div element.

Comment: the div was inserted for simplicity, it is an <img> tag in the actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add below line in css code part may help to solve the indentation issue.

```
.row {margin: 0 -1px;}
```

Modified code:

```
  <div class="card-body" style="max-width: 400px">                          
    <span class="rounded logo-container" style="float:right;max-width: 40%;">
  <div style="height: 60px; width: 80px;background: red" alt="Logo" ></div>
    </span>



<div class="container-fluid p-0">

<p style="margin:0 13px;"><b>ASDASDASDASD</b></p>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col" style="max-width: 6em">sadfasdf:</div>
    <div class="col">sdfasdf</div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col" style="max-width: 6em">safdasdfasdf:</div>
            <div class="col">sdfsadfsadfasdf</div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col" style="max-width: 6em">sadfasdfsa:</div>
            <div class="col">afsdafs dfsdfsadsdgdfgfs sdfsadf</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Modified JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/pkgscdm6/4/)

Output in Edge:

[image]

Output in FireFox:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, this fixed the issue, I ended up using m-0 class on the rows in the actual code